# ColdFusion if then statement related to HTML

Tags: html, coldfusion

Hi I am pretty new to ColdFusion. My company still uses it. I have the following code I have tweaked. It seems to be working fine.

Basically I want to say where CountyName is null, do not display the county HTML code. When CountyName is not null, do show it.

```
<cfif isdefined("URL.LOCAL") and isdefined("URL.STATE_NO") is "true">
  <!----- If Local is the County (Contains the word County), the local 
   will be the County. (Do not want duplicate County results) ------>

  <cfif "#URL.LOCAL#" CONTAINS "County">
    <cfset LocalName="#URL.LOCAL#">
    <cfset StateNo=#URL.STATE_NO#>

    <!----- If Local is the City (does not contain the word County), 
    add the County code in addition to the City --->
  <cfelse> 
    <cfset LocalName="#URL.LOCAL#">
    <cfset CountyName="#URL.COUNTY#">
    <cfset StateNo=#URL.STATE_NO#>
  </cfif>

<cfelse> 
  <cfset LocalName="Madison">
  <cfset StateNo=1>
</cfif>
```

**Update:**

I just tried the following and it works fine in my HTML:

```
<cfif isdefined("URL.COUNTY") is "true">
  <p class="reportHeader_fontSemiBig">
    <cfoutput>#CountyName#</cfoutput> Property Codes
  </p>
<cfelse>
  <p>No county info</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Are you getting an error? Are the results not what you expect?

Comment: @Evik - If the `url.county` is defined, but has no value, the true case of the `cfif` statement in the output code would execute. I'm sure that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry I kind of answered my own question. I should have added a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to the existing answer, but I'm going to explain things a little bit.

`isDefined("url.county")` just checks that the key `county` exists in the url scope. It doesn't check that there is a value. In ColdFusion you can drop the `is true` or `gt 0` for evaluations and just check that the key exists and that there is a length to the key. If it was all spaces this would return false.

```
<cfif isdefined("URL.COUNTY") AND len(trim(url.county))>
  <p class="reportHeader_fontSemiBig">
    <cfoutput>#CountyName#</cfoutput> Property Codes
  </p>
<cfelse>
  <p>No county info</p>
</cfif>
```

In earlier versions of ColdFusion `isDefined()` used to be quite slow, but that's not the case anymore, but following best practice I would recommend using `structKeyExists(url, 'County')` instead of `isDefined("url.county")`

Comment: @Andrew - One of the main reasons `structKeyExists` is preferred, over `isDefined` is precision. Due to how `isDefined` evaluates variables, it is less precise and can lead to unexpected results in some situations. Do a search on "isdefined vs structkeyexists" for more details and examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for:

```
<cfif isdefined("url.county") and url.county NEQ ''>
<p class="reportHeader_fontSemiBig">
<cfoutput>#CountyName#</cfoutput> Property Codes </p>
<cfelse>
<p>No county info</p>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif isdefined("url.county") and url.county NEQ ''>
<p>
<cfoutput>#url.County#</cfoutput> Property Codes </p>
<cfelse>
<p>No county info</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: `url.country` is not necessarily `countryname`. See Frank's example